# drupal maximum execution time of cron

Tags: drupal, cron, execution-time

Whats the maximum execution time of cron. is it possible to modify it if so any side effects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The accepted answer above is INCORRECT. Cron's time limit in Drupal is hardcoded to 240 seconds. See the `drupal_cron_run` function in `includes/common.inc`, specifically these lines:

```
drupal_set_time_limit(240);
```

and

```
if (!lock_acquire('cron', 240.0)) {
```

(based on the source of Drupal 7.12)

So, there is no way to change this globally without hacking core. I have heard it suggested to call `drupal_set_time_limit` yourself inside of your `hook_cron` implementation, as doing so resets PHP's counter. However that won't help you when it's a third-party module implementing `hook_cron`.

Comment: As of Drupal 8.7, the number is still 240 seconds, but it is set in `web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php`: `Environment::setTimeLimit(240);`

Answer (score 3):

Maximum execution time for Drupal's cron depends on your `php.ini`.

For example if you use `wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/cron.php` as your cron command, apache's php.ini is used to determine the maximum execution time.

If you use `php -f cron.php` as your cron command, then php-cli's php.ini is used to determine the maximum execution time.

It is recommended to use php-cli for higher execution time, where you can set the maximum execution time from `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` (if you use debian linux) and have no side effects on apache while cron runs.

Comment: +1, but a word of warning when invoking cron via cli: Make sure that none of your modules `hook_cron()` implementations relies on using variables provided by the web server, as they will obviously not available in that context (spent quite some time once to find that a module used `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` on cron invocations).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is necessarily the case as I've just run the `cron.php` through my browser and I'm getting a `max excution time error` of 240 seconds while my max execution time in my php.ini is 1200 seconds.  So somewhere besides my php.ini file Drupal is grabbing the max execution time.

That somewhere would be in the `./includes/common.inc` or `./includes/locale.inc`.  Head into there and there are settings to adjust how long drupal will allow the cron to run for before giving up

Answer (score 0):

This module can help you: [Set Cron Time](https://drupal.org/sandbox/AlexanderHadjHassine/2069771)